# How to create a .key file given a public private key pair in integer form

Tags: openssl, rsa

I am performing cryptanalysis and I have a public key file using which I calculated the private key in integer form. Now I want to decrypt another message using it in openssl for which I need to create a .key file of the private key. How can I create a .key file given the private key. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can create your integer to big number which is basically `BIGNUM` structure of OpenSSL and then assign to `RSA` structure.

Now, you can write `RSA` to file.

```
RSA *pubkey = RSA_new();

/*
    RSA private key is basically d and n. You already have n as you have public key.
    You may have computed d or p and q.
    First read the private key from the file into a char * buffer say p.
    Depending on the fact whether your integer is in hex or decimal, you can use
    BN_hex2bn or BN_dec2bn.

    Depending on what you have computed d or p and q, assign it to RSA structure.
    I assume that you may have computed d.
*/

//Depending on the fact whether your integer is in hex or decimal, you can use    
int len = BN_hex2bn(&pubkey->d, (const char *)p);
// or int len = BN_hex2bn(&pubkey->d, (const char *)p);

if (len == 0 || p[len])
    fprintf(stderr, "'%s' does not appear to be a valid number.\n", p);

/*Now, you use private key. either to decrypt or sign.*/
/*Or write your private key using d2i_RSAPrivateKey_fp or using PEM 
  which you can search through OpenSSL.
*/
```